# OIDC config blocked in Forgerock by CORS

Tags: angular, openid-connect, forgerock

my application adds “Origin: http://localhost:8000” header to the discovery url GET request that causes Forgerock return CORS Error. It happens even when global CORS Filter is disabled in Forgerock. I’ve tried adding redirect url to localhost, couldn’t find any ‘web origins’ list in config.  I’m using angular-oauth2-oidc library for connection.
How can I set forgerock to ignore/accept this header?

Thanks in advance

I've already tried:

- changing localhost name in hosts file (any Origin header returns 403)
- disabling cors by flag in Chrome
- testing multiple different headers in Postman, only "Origin" blocks from response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually the configuration of Tomcat running forgerock. Brand new installation with new .war solved issues.